# Php file text parsing

Tags: php

I'm having a problem with the following php code:

#### Code

```
<?php
    $file = fopen("res/changelog","r");
    while(! feof($file))
    {
        $line = fgets($file);
        if (strlen($line) > 0){
            if (substr($line, 0, 1) === "#"){
                echo "<h2>", substr($line, 1), "</h2><br />"
            }
            else {
                echo "<p>", $line, "</p><br />";
            }
        }
    }

    fclose($file);
?>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to parse text from a file and transform it into HTML elements using php.
For some reason, when I try to load the page, it's white.

Can anyone tell me the possible cause of the issue and how to fix it?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Add some debug statements. Your code only has two places that will cause output, so it looks like it's not reaching them.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to do what I wanted by recoding it differently.
Here's what I use now:

#### Code

```
<?php
    $file = fopen("res/changelog","r");
    echo "<p>";
    while(! feof($file))
    {
        $line = fgets($file);
        if (substr($line, 0, 1) === "#")
        {
            echo "</p><h2>", substr($line, 1), "</h2><p>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo $line, "<br />";
        }
    }
    echo "</p>";
    fclose($file);
?>
```

I still don't know why the previous code didn't work, so if you know what the cause may be, I'll be more than happy to read your explanation.

I'm sorry for posting the question before taking some time to fix it.

Comment: It's not an explanation why your code failed, but I think this should be a bit shorter: http://pastebin.com/VxyqutME <- Does that works for you?

Comment: @Rizier123 This works for me and seems simpler than my working code, thank you